# take input as your name, then calculate the max and min of ASCII values(excluding space between first & last name)of all the letters of your name

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

When running the code, the minimum value error occurs. How can I fix it?

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter your first and last name: "
max_msg: .asciiz "\nMaximum ASCII value: "
min_msg: .asciiz "\nMinimum ASCII value: "
newline: .asciiz "\n"

.text
.globl main

main:
    # Prompt for input
    li $v0, 4       # system call for print string
    la $a0, prompt  # load address of prompt
    syscall

    # Read input
    li $v0, 8       # system call for read string
    la $a0, buffer  # load address of buffer
    li $a1, 255     # set maximum length of input
    syscall

    # Find maximum and minimum ASCII values
    la $t0, buffer   # load address of buffer into $t0

    li $t1, 0x20     # initialize $t1 to the ASCII value of space
    li $t2, 0x7F     # initialize $t2 to the largest possible ASCII value
    li $t3, 0x00     # initialize $t3 to the smallest possible ASCII value
    li $t4, 0         # initialize $t4 to 0

loop:
    lb $t5, ($t0)    # load byte from current position
    beq $t5, 0, done # if byte is null terminator, we're done

    # if byte is a space, skip it
    beq $t5, $t1, next

    # if this is the first non-space character, initialize $t4
    beq $t4, 0, init

    # find maximum ASCII value
    bgt $t5, $t3, is_max
    j is_min

is_max:
    move $t3, $t5    # set $t3 to current byte
    j next

    # find minimum ASCII value
is_min:
    blt $t5, $t2, set_min
    j next

set_min:
    move $t2, $t5    # set $t2 to current byte
    j next

init:
    # initialize $t4 to the first non-space character
    move $t4, $t5
    j next

next:
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 # move to next byte
    j loop           # jump to loop

done:
    # Print results
    li $v0, 4         # system call for print string
    la $a0, max_msg   # load address of max message
    syscall

    li $v0, 1         # system call for print integer
    move $a0, $t3     # load maximum ASCII value
    syscall

    li $v0, 4         # system call for print string
    la $a0, min_msg   # load address of min message
    syscall

    li $v0, 1         # system call for print integer
    move $a0, $t2     # load minimum ASCII value
    syscall

    li $v0, 4         # system call for print string
    la $a0, newline   # load address of newline
    syscall

    # Exit program
    li $v0, 10        # set system call number to 10 for exit
    syscall           # perform system call to exit
.data
buffer: .space 256   # allocate space for input buffer
```

Here the maximum ascii value of my name is coming right but the minimum value is coming wrong.

**My Output:**

Enter your first and last name: Isaac Newton
Maximum ASCII value:  119
Minimum ASCII value: 10

**My expected output:**

Enter your first and last name: Isaac Newton
Maximum ASCII value:  119
Minimum ASCII value: 73

How can I fix it?

Comment: You should not process the line feed at the end of input. Either stop there instead of a 0 or use one less than the length returned from the `read`.

Answer (score 1):

The [MIPS system call 8](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html) is similar to fgets() in C such that it includes a *newline* at the end of the input. You should be checking for the ascii value for a newline, which, as you may have guessed, is 10.

Now, how come it was stopping *after* the newline character? Well, <strike>the rest of the buffer</strike> the buffer is padded with a *single* null character. This is why it was *always* setting minValue to be 10, and terminating the program immediately after. All you need to do to fix your problem is implement a check to look for chars with an ascii value of 10 (in your case you could very likely just change `beq $t5, 0, done` to `beq $t5, 10, done`). I hope that helps to clear up any confusion you may be having.

Edit: *As mentioned below by Peter, this implementation can lead to vulnerabilities in the program. For a wonderful explanation as to why, please see their comments down below.*

Comment: `$v0=8`  / `syscall` is 100% guaranteed to store a `0` terminator itself (old buffer contents don't matter), but only one; it doesn't fill the rest of the buffer.  A newline is only stored if the buffer was large enough for the input line.  That's likely with a size of 256, but if you search for a `'\n'` instead of `0`, someone could break your program (read past the end of the .data or BSS section) by inputting an extremely long line, like holding down a key for many seconds.

Comment: So a robust program would check for a 0 terminator, then check that the previous character was a newline, then use the character before that.  A toy program could still check for a `0` (with `lb` / ... / `bne $t5, $zero, top_of_loop`), then take *two* characters before that, assuming the skipped one was a newline.  (On real OSes, read system calls return a length in a register.  It's really dumb that SPIM / MARS toy system calls don't do that.)

Comment: But yeah, since the OP is finding min/max on the fly, just looking for a newline is much easier, and fine for a toy program. It's not important that malicious user-input can make it crash.  Or since they're already skipping spaces, they could also check for newline, if they wanted to make it robust (and make a function that would work on arbitrary string input, not just single lines.)

Comment: Interesting, I suppose I was misremembering about the buffer - thank you for the correction! You make some great points about the integrity of simply checking for a newline character. I agree that a robust program would have to do more than simply check for a newline character. That would simply not suffice. But, given the simplicity of OPs program, I think that would be a tad overkill ;)

Comment: Teaching good habits (of safe programming) is generally a good thing, but yeah sometimes it would distract too much from the basic problem, or introduce more complication.  When writing answers myself, I prefer to point out the assumption that we can make for a toy program, when recommending something that's only a good idea in a toy program for learning purposes.  In this case, these comments hopefully won't get deleted by people flagging them as no longer needed, but that can happen so you might want to edit if you have time.